# How do we remove the infinite number in Beta distribution output form scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, bayesian

I computed a beta posterior distribution like the image below. This beta distribution has a Jeffreys prior to make the distribution smooth. When one of the beta input values contains 0, one of the outputs of beta.pdf contains inf. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I am interested in extracting the 40 values within this beta.pdf distribution.

[image]

Comment: The code is unclear - where is `j_read_3` used? Also, beta parameters range over positive reals - a prior that yields a nonpositive is invalid.